# How do I specify the custom schema for knex migration and lock files?

Tags: node.js, database, migration, knex.js

I want to specify a custom schemaName in knexFile but the schema does not exist yet.

```
const config = {
  client: "postgresql",
  connection: {
    database: DB_NAME,
    user: DB_USER,
    password: DB_PASSWORD,
    host: DB_HOST,
  },
   migrations: {
    schemaName: "custom_schema",
    tableName: "knex_migrations",
  },
};
```

But when I run my migrations, it says custom_schema does not exist. How do I create a schema before creating the knex_migration and knex_migration_lock files?

Comment: schemaName here is the schema where the migration table (knex_migrations) exists.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that I got working is below.

1. Use environment variables to set the schema
2. In migration files, use withSchema as below.

   ```
   exports.up = function(knex) {
      const schemaName = process.env.schemaName;
      return knex.schema.withSchema(schemaName).table("applications", function(table){
          table.smallint("version").notNullable().defaultTo(1).alter();
      });      
   };
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As I see KNEX APIs does not support specifying schema while running migrations. There is an attempt here https://www.npmjs.com/package/knex-migration-with-schema that I am evaluating currently. This module has a function to create schema as well.